# moving the index to different location of binary file

Tags: java, android

i have a map file which has several tile images in the form of binary data. now i have to jump my index to different location of the file and read that tile. but i could not find anything helpful for me i also checked mark() and skip() methods.but not helping me.

is there any method or class which can do what exactly i want or any hint you want to give me

thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RandomAccessFile](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)  may be helpful to you. [Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) is how to use them.

Random access files permit nonsequential, or random, access to a file's contents. To access a file randomly, you open the file, seek a particular location, and read from or write to that file.

Comment: Is there any other Class except this for that purpose? becuase i am using streams for reading the file specially SwappedDataInputStreams for endian stuff.